# highcharts customEvents.js issue 0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected

Tags: highcharts

I am using Pawel Fus's `customEvents.js` for highcharts.
I have created [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/enHuKjfL7ZPj7SvBCUZ2?p=preview) plunkr and i have a functionality for title click.
The functionality works fine but it throws debugging error

```
 0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected
```

on line -

```
serie.group.clip(serie.customClipPath);
```

Is there something wrong that i am doing?

Comment: This seems like a bug and is already reported - https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events/issues/22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed and the functionality works as expected.